# Loading ViewController before loading Data is IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my ViewController I load my TableView data from a mySQL server online.
When I press the button that load the ViewController, it takes time before loading the ViewController.

Although my data is being called after viewDidLoad method ..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    MyData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    MySqlDataBase *mySql = [[MySqlDataBase alloc]init];
    MyArray = [mySql doQueryGetArray:@"SELECT * FROM member" ForDataBaseWithName:@"Estifta"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[MyArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"text"]);
    [_myTabeView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called when your view is loaded into the memory but *before* the view is displayed on screen. Your code in viewDidLoad runs on the mainThread (UIThread) and therefore slows the display of the view on screen.

As solution you could dispatch the long running parts on a background queue (using dispatch_async) and afterwards reload the tableview on the main thread.

```
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
MySqlDataBase *mySql = [[MySqlDataBase alloc]init];        
MyArray = [mySql doQueryGetArray:@"SELECT * FROM member" ForDataBaseWithName:@"Estifta"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf.myTabeView reloadData];
        });
    });
```

Comment: You do not need the weak reference to `self` here.

Comment: @rmaddy - I think this depends on the duration of the async SQL query. In some circumstances, it could happen that we hold the strong reference to *self* longer than necessary. Therefore I think it's a bit cleaner to have just a weak reference to self.

Comment: Good point. If the view controller is dismissed before the query completes, that would be a good reason to use a weak self. I was just thinking about its use to prevent a reference cycle which isn't an issue with that code.